# Toolbar covers fragment text

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I want to have text in the top app bar but the text is not showing. This is the xml file for the fragment. In "design" everything seems fine but when I launch it on the emulator it is just the bar without the text. Does somebody has any idea how to fix this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Fragments.GrowthFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/green">

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:text="About us"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="28dp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
'''
```

Comment: Please show your screenshot or layout-inspector. Anw, why don't you use `Toolbar.setTitle("About us")` instead?